# Doing pandas join with multiple values on the left and one on the right

Tags: python, pandas, join

I'm looking for help joining two datasets in pandas.

My first dataset is a contacts dataset, including name and an ID. The second is a deals dataset which amongst other fields includes one column with a number of comma separated contact IDs. I would like to left join the deals dataset to the contacts dataset where the contact ID matches one of the IDs in the 'associated contacts' field.

```html
contacts_df = pd.DataFrame(
  {'name': ['John Smith', 'Jane Doe', 'James Bond'],
  'id': [1,2,3]}
  

deals_df = pd.DataFrame(
  {'deal_name': ['McDonalds', 'KFC'],
  'associated_contacts':['1,3','2']}
```

I have split the contacts in the deals dataframe into four different columns:

```html
deals_df[['Contact ID 1','Contact ID 2','Contact ID 3', 'Contact ID 4']] = deals_df['associated_contacts'].str.split(',',expand=True)
```

And tried to join this to the contacts dataset:

```
merged = contacts_df.merge(deals_df, how='left', left_on='id', 
                    right_on=['Contact ID 1','Contact ID 2','Contact ID 3','Contact ID 4'])
```

But that returned a ValueError:

```
ValueError: len(right_on) must equal len(left_on)
```

Can anyone help me join these two datasets please? I think in my dataset each contact will only be associated with one deal. But a deal could have multiple contacts and I'd like to see the deal associated with each one.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) (pandas 0.25+) for repeat values of `associated_contacts` splitted by `,`, laso is necessary convert column `id` to integers:

```
deals_df = (deals_df.assign(id = deals_df.pop('associated_contacts').str.split(','))
                    .explode('id')
                    .assign(id = lambda x: x['id'].astype(int)))
print (deals_df)
   deal_name  id
0  McDonalds   1
0  McDonalds   3
1        KFC   2
```

Your solution should be changed with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original:

```
deals_df = (deals_df.join(deals_df.pop('associated_contacts')
                                  .str.split(',', expand=True)
                                  .stack()
                                  .astype(int)
                                  .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
                                  .rename('id')))
print (deals_df)
0  McDonalds   1
0  McDonalds   3
1        KFC   2
```

And then use `merge` with parameter `on` only:

```
merged = contacts_df.merge(deals_df, how='left', on='id')
print (merged)
         name  id  deal_name
0  John Smith   1  McDonalds
1    Jane Doe   2        KFC
2  James Bond   3  McDonalds
```